# Set UIKeyboardAppearance across the whole app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uikeyboard

Is there a useful property in a cocoa-touch project that would allow setting the one-and-only consistent style of keyboard appearance throughout the app? Say I want `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert` on all the textFields and textViews I have in my app without directly modifying anything. Is is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. The `keyboardAppearance` is part of the `UITextInputTraits` protocol and is not marked as a UIAppearance method. If it was you could do something like:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

You can identify methods that can be used with the appearance proxy by looking at the docs or, from within your code, at the UIKit headers (command-click on a method and it will take you to the header.

For example, in UINavigationBar.h, you can see this:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *barTintColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;  // default is nil
```

The marker UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR means that this property can be used on the appearance proxy. It isn't present on `keyboardAppearance`, and it doesn't look like any keys in the info.plist allow you to define an application-wide appearance.

Your best bet is to subclass textfield and textview and use those subclasses everywhere.

Comment: Actually on iOS7 if you call `[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];` it works, even if the property has no UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR decorator

Comment: Luca's code worked for me with UITextField, but my app crashed when I tried to do the same thing with UITextView.