# Change the keyboardAppearence for the whole app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uitextview

With iOS7, the protocol `UITextInputTraits` gets new values for the enum `UIKeyboardAppearance`. 
In particular I'm interested in changing the `keyboardAppearance` to `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark` in order to match the current app dark design.

I first looked into the Info.plist but it seems that there isn't a key in that allows you to globally set this property.

My second thought was to use the UIAppearance but unfortunately the `keyboardAppearance` doesn't have the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` decorator. 
But for some reason this code:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
```

works on iOS7, but crashes in iOS6.

Even more strangely the following code:

```
[[UITextView appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
```

doesn't work in iOS7 nor iOS6.

A good idea can be to create a subclass of both UITextField & UITextView but in this way this doesn't work for example in UISearchBar.

I don't want to create a category because I don't want to sort-of-override the implementation of Apple classes and probably not been future proof.

Any one have ever dealt with this?

Comment: Doesn't look like it's possible :(
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19032824/484780

Comment: I created a small category for this. Will post soon.

Answer (score 4):

Use this control
https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setOverrideKeyboardAppearance:YES];
    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
    return YES;
}
```

It is mainly used to manage the distance between keyboard & textField but your issue can also be resolved via this great library.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is a good one, worked for me as I wanted to change the appearance of my apps keyboard. In fact, earlier I tried it  by writing my own Keyboard by modifying a UIView with an image pasted on it, but it was like reinventing the wheel.